# Get entire days timestamp with secs in python

Tags: python, datetime, time-series, timestamp

I need to trying to get entire days timestamp in array. I need from **00:00:00 to 24:00:00** seconds of timestamp a day i.e **86400 data.**

I have used pandas to achieve but could not

```
m_days=1
# today's date in timestamp
base = pd.Timestamp.today()

timestamp_list = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(n_days)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it then:

```
import pandas as pd

start = pd.Timestamp('2022-02-16')  # start of the day
end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=1)  # end of the day

timestamps = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='s')
```

Comment: what I need is entire days timestamp not just one instances.

Comment: so you want the result from this?
import pandas as pd
start = pd.Timestamp('2022-02-16')  # start of the day
end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=1)  # end of the day
timestamps = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='s')

Comment: yeah this works, edit the answer and include the code :)

Comment: Done - enjoy :)

Comment: Is there any way to skip 4 sec, i mean get all 1,5,10,15 .. secs data ?

Comment: for every 4 seconds u should set freq='4s'
and if you wanna start it at 00:00:01 you need to add "+ pd.offsets.Second(1) " to the start value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251957/discussion-between-fallouthase-and-suhas-rkms).